# How can I rewrite migration history on Django?

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.7. I have a Dev environment and a Stage environment. They are sync'ed (that is, they have the same codebase) and everything's very easy.

I made a mistake: deployed a branch on Stage, applied a migration, and forgot to revert that migration when changing branches. I merged the migrations to get the deploy out (you know how it is sometimes) and now the environments have diverged.

So now my deployment script (yeah, yeah, should use Fab or something like that, but I have a script and that's that -- and maybe a different implementation wouldn't have left me with this problem, but here we are) ... as I was saying, my deployment script now doesn't work, because Stage won't migrate automatically, I have to merge it every time.

I don't want to do any more migration reverting. I'd just like to rewrite Stage's migration history with Dev's migration history. Is that possible?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Migration history is stored in the database itself, in the `django_migrations` table. If you want to remove the record of a migration, delete the corresponding row from this table.

Comment: Isn't it `django_migrations`?